# nVidia graphics card output doesn't work

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

I've been having an issue lately, my graphics card ([Asus GTX 560 ti](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051E3BYM)) refuses to output a signal through the mini HDMI port, my screen only has HDMI and VGA so I can't try DVI port.

Thinking I had some hardware problem I removed the card from the first PCI slot and placed it in the 2nd. I also placed an old AMD Radeon HD 5400 graphics card and plugged the screen to it, I managed to boot and get to the device manager window, Nvidia card is detected but shows an error code `43`.

I updated the drivers but can't seem to get it to work, any ideas how can I fix it ?

Motherboard: Asus P8P67 PRO
CPU: i7, 
OS: Windows 8 64 bit.

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Do you intend to use both at the same time, or are just using the AMD GPU to try to fix the nVidia card?

Comment: I am just using it to fix the nvidia card

Comment: Have you read [GTX 560 Ti Code 43](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/386636-33-code) and the many related resources link at the end?

Comment: I've checked the registry files, updated the drivers and restarted. those were the 3 proposed solutions and none did work